# my gateway laptop will not reboot

Tags: reboot, reset

My gateway laptop model nx570xl originally rebooted normally.  I don't know when it happened, but now when I try to reboot it keeps trying, but it never happens, forcing me to shut down and wait a random amount of time before it will start up again.

It's very annoying and wastes a lot of my time.  I don't think it's a CPU overheating problem because it's random when it starts up  after I turn it back on.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turns on and half, but not a normal restart. Have you tried doing so with just the power cable and no battery, and have you tried from within safe mode.

Comment: At what point does it get hung up? Is the screen already black or do you still see the windows background?

Comment: Screen is already black

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? XP? Vista? 7?

Comment: Vista home premium

Comment: So can I confirm, when you force shut down, afterwords you can't turn it on, does the power button do nothing, does it turn on and turn off, or does it turn on with a black screen and just hear the machine running but that's it.

Comment: If the answer below works out, please don't forget to mark it with the green check mark! Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

This is likely caused by a background program (likely a system process that you are not familiar with) that refuses to close. Unfortunately I don't know of any easy way to identify which one it is, but you can swing into the dark with an [application like ccleaner.](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)

Use the application and registry cleaner features. Can take up to 15-20 minutes. Try doing a reboot after that.

It still no dice, [look into](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02gq81JKjhA) the ["StartUp" programs section in the same tool.](https://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/using-ccleaner/managing-auto-starting-programs) It may be that one of those is the culprit.

If you are really feeling adventurous you could download a Live CD/DVD/USB Linux distro ([Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)?), boot from it and then initiate a shutdown. This will rule out whether something has gone wrong with the hardware or not.

Comment: Interesting. Thx..i have used advanced system care on many occasions and have had the same problem afterwards after it fixes the registry

Answer (score -1):

For general non-boot issues like this here is my process:
Start by making sure you have a back of the data/files on the machine. This usually does a couple of things:

- A.) it makes sure you don't loose anything.
- B.) if you don't already have a backup it gives you piece of mind
- C.) it allows you to just kind of give up and reimage/reload windows.
- D.) if you start trying to backup of a damaged machine and it fails then you know it's probably a harddrive failure of some kind.

Whew, hopefully your data is safe now. Next is to stress test your harddrive. I like to use the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) for that because it's free, requires no OS, and is reliable. There are several other tools like it though, including some of the newer live CD's. If your harddrive passes, then you can either keep trying to troubleshoot windows or reload/reimage. If it fails, you have no choice but to replace it and reload.

Assuming you now have your data safe, and a confirmed good harddrive your next step is to see if you can get into safe mode. If you can start looking a selective boot/clean boot, slowly adding things until you can't. Whatever you last added that stopped you from booting is your issue.

If you cannot boot into safemode then personally I think you're best to reload here, why because you're already so unstable you're in trouble. In the XP days you could try a repair install, and in the vista/win7 days they have [startup repair](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/startup-repair) options but to be honest I think you're rolling the dice in terms of system stability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You guys are really knowledgeable.is there any way i can email myself your comments so UK have them in front it'd me as i diagnose?

Comment: So ill have them in front of me?

Comment: you could always copy and paste them into word or something and then print them. I have no idea if there is a way to email them to yourself though.